# Find equal range for container with string with prefix

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, equal-range

I am having 2 iterators range_begin,range_end, which are my container. I need to find all string which start with char prefix.
Here is my code:

```
template <typename RandomIt>
pair<RandomIt, RandomIt> FindStartsWith(
RandomIt range_begin, RandomIt 
range_end,char prefix){
auto it=equal_range(range_begin,range_end,prefix,
[prefix](const string& city){return city[0]==prefix;});
return it;}
```

For example, for

```
const vector<string> sorted_strings = {"moscow", "murmansk", "vologda"};
auto it=FindStartsWith(strings.begin(),strings.end(),'m');
```

I want to get iterator with first on "moscow" and last after "murmansk".

I am getting strange compilier errors. What is wrong and how can I solve this?I cannot write correct lambda comporator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors might be due to **strings.begin()** and .end() which do not have **sorted_**. I do not think you should use a template either.  Errors aside, I recommend you use a different std function. A simpler solution is to use foreach:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator RandomIt;

std::vector<std::string> FindStartsWith(RandomIt start, RandomIt end, const char prefix) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::for_each(start, end, [&](auto city) {
        if (city.front() == prefix) {
          result.push_back(city);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::vector<std::string> sorted_strings = { "moscow", "murmansk", "vologda" };
    auto prefix_cities = FindStartsWith(sorted_strings.begin(), sorted_strings.end(), 'm');

    return 0;
}
```

Definitely could use a refactor, but I'm assuming you need to implement it in the FindStartsWith for some other reason...

Thanks for posting, this taught me a lot about equal_range :)

Answer (score 2):

`equal_range` expects a comparison function that takes two parameters; you are passing a function taking one.

A heterogeneous call (one where the type of `value` is not the same as the type elements in the range) requires a comparison function that can take the two types in either order. A lambda won't work in this case as it only has one `operator()` overload.

Finally, the function must perform a *less-than* type of comparison, not an *equals* one. Roughly, `equal_range` returns a range from the first element for which `!(element < value)` to the first element for which `value < element`.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

The reason for your compile error is hidden in the implementations of comparators in two functions "lower_bound" and "upper_bound" which call from the main function "equal_range".

1. [EQUAL_RANGE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)

   ```
   template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
   pair<ForwardIt,ForwardIt> 
       equal_range(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
                   const T& value, Compare comp)
   {
       return make_pair(lower_bound(first, last, value, comp),
                             upper_bound(first, last, value, comp));
   }
   ```

Make attention to how the comparator is caused in each function. Look that comparators are caused by different sequences of arguments and this is the reason for the error.

2. [LOWER_BOUND](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

   ```
   if (comp(*it, value))
   ```
3. [UPPER_BOUND](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

   ```
   if (!comp(value, *it))
   ```

**ADDITIONAL INFOMATION**

Below I copied an example of implementations of two functions accordingly.

LOWER_BOUND:

````
```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt lower_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
 
    while (count > 0) {
        it = first;
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (comp(*it, value)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        }
        else
            count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```
````

UPPER_BOUND:

````
```
template<class ForwardIt, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIt upper_bound(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value, Compare comp)
{
    ForwardIt it;
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type count, step;
    count = std::distance(first, last);
 
    while (count > 0) {
        it = first; 
        step = count / 2;
        std::advance(it, step);
        if (!comp(value, *it)) {
            first = ++it;
            count -= step + 1;
        } 
        else
            count = step;
    }
    return first;
}
```
````

**SOLUTION**

You have two ways to solve this problem (maybe more).

1. Write two comparators for each function and call each other separatively.
2. Convert *char* argument to *string*, write comparator for strings and call equal_range.